# "No more dirty dishes shall meet the eye."

Tags: expressions

My flatmates frequently make a huge mess in our kitchen.

I created a motivational poster to hang in our kitchen with a picture of Optimus Prime and the phrase:

"Optimus Prime says: No more dirty dishes shall meet the eye!" (as a reference to the Transformers catchphrase "more than meets the eye")

I'm not a native speaker—so, does that work?

Comment: I've read through the four answers already provided and cannot argue that the question title is grammatically incorrect, ***but***... ...a part of me *really* wants to split that infinite and move 'shall' before 'dirty dishes'.  "No more *shall* dirty dishes meet the eye."

Comment: @oosterwal - To me, "No more shall dirty dishes meet the eye." moves it into the realm of a victory speech rather than a boldly stated intention. "Blackguard, prepare to die!" becomes "Rejoice! The wicked witch is dead!"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether it *works* or not is up to your roommates, but as a native (North American) English speaker, I think it's above average.

Answer (score 1):

If you're a non-native speaker I think you can congratulate yourself on coming up with a pretty reasonable turn of phrase there. But as mickeyf says, it only *works* if your flatmates get with the program!

It may therefore be slightly nit-picking, but I have to say I think "No more dirty dishes shall meet the eye!" implies "meet *your* eye" (the flatmate's)...

...and that this implies (since Optimus Prime *himself* is giving the undertaking) that *he* will be doing the washing-up. That might be what you'd all like, but frankly I think you'll have a long wait!

Answer (score 1):

Full marks for grammar and content. The archaic tone of the phrasing lends it an air of gravity.

I, too, have my doubts that the slovenly flatmates will shape up (but it pays to think positively).

Answer (score 0):

*Shall* is a modal verb that can be used to express a strong assertion or intention. Think of Gandalf in *The Fellowship of the Ring* (film) saying to the Balrog:

> You shall not *pass*!

So, yes, given the context and the purpose, consider it a way of humorously baring your teeth and snarling at your filthy roommates and their disgusting habits.